# Flutter plugin configuration issue

Tags: ios, flutter, dart-pub, flutter-dependencies

I am working on a flutter project which uses local database. For local database I am using `sqflite` plugin https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqflite. My application is working fine without installing sqflite. However, as soon as I install `sqflite`. It stops running for ios. I am receiving below errors.

> import 
>   1 error generated.
>   === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
>   In file included from /Users/user/Documents/DEVELOPMENT/Flutter_Dev/Flutter_project/FlutterDatabaseSQFLite-master/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.m:1:
>   /Users/user/Documents/DEVELOPMENT/Flutter_Dev/Flutter_project/FlutterDatabaseSQFLite-master/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.h:2:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
>   import 
>   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   1 error generated.
>   /Users/user/Documents/DEVELOPMENT/Flutter_Dev/Flutter_project/FlutterDatabaseSQFLite-master/ios/Runner/main.m:2:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
>   import 
>   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   1 error generated.
>   === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
>   ld: file not found: /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ctqhqjwcexxoquevqxydctpmagio/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   Could not build the application for the simulator.
>   Error launching application on iPhone 8 Plus.

. And the strange thing is after this error, if I create new project of flutter it gives me below error.

> /Users/user/Documents/DEVELOPMENT/Flutter_Dev/Flutter_project/local_db/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.h:1:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found import  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 1 error generated. === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug === /Users/user/Documents/DEVELOPMENT/Flutter_Dev/Flutter_project/local_db/ios/Runner/main.m:1:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found #import  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 1 error generated. === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug === In file included from /Users/user/Documents/DEVELOPMENT/Flutter_Dev/Flutter_project/local_db/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:5: /Users/user/Documents/DEVELOPMENT/Flutter_Dev/Flutter_project/local_db/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:8:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found #import  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 1 error generated. === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug === ld: file not found: /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-eqhuhphzvosrgvdilnpudqzvakju/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching application on iPhone 8 Plus.

And the application stops working. Here is the output of `flutter doctor` command.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v0.8.7-pre.6, on Mac OS X 10.14 18A384a,       locale en-IN)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.2)
! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.27.2)
[✓] Connected devices (1 available)
```

Please help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Flutter channel from Master to Beta

In the terminal open the flutter directory and set the export path the type

```
flutter channel beta
```

Comment: I am already in beta channel. I have tried with master channel as well but no luck.

Comment: okay, the code you shared refers to the Master version hence why I asked. What version of cocopods are you running?

Comment: Cocoapods version 1.5.0

Comment: you could try upgrading to 1.6.0 beta 1

Comment: It works fine with other machine with same cocoapod version

Comment: in that case you should uninstall everything and reinstall.

Comment: I have tried to remove the flutter directory and removed the path from bash.profile and again install it but still get the same issue